# Use .toggle() to conditionally hide and show.

Tags: jquery, html

Im using jQuery and datatables to create a list of properties in a table. I also have a row of buttons that are property features that I wish to use to show and hide properties in the list based on the user click.

For example, this is my feature filter. A simple row of buttons that I use to toggle the tr elements in the property table below:

```
<div>
  <span class="button" id="pool">Pool</span>
  <span class="button" id="bar">Bar</span>
  <span class="button" id="club">Club</span>
  <span class="button" id="beach">Beach</span>
</div>
```

This is the property table.

```
<table>
  <tr class="pool bar">
    <td>some info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="pool">
    <td>some info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="club bar">
    <td>some info</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using the script below. 
1. Adds .buttonSelected to the span to change the background colour.
2. If I click span#pool to hide properties with a pool (tr.pool), then click span#bar to hide rows with a bar (tr.bar), this just toggles tr.pool back on again.

```
jQuery('.features_toggle span.button').on('click',function(){

    var feature = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    jQuery(this).toggleClass('buttonSelected');

    jQuery('.elegant_list_properties tr.'+feature).toggle();

});
```

I need to be able to keep the row hidden even if other features are toggled.

Comment: Can you please post a working code snippet?

Comment: Ok I tried to simplify what I had as its quite complicated but Ill setup a fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sqmcLgz7/2/
Click on panoramic sea view and guardian in the filters. You'll see what I mean.

Comment: What do you expect on clicking `Panoramic Sea View` and then on clicking `Giardian`?

Comment: Click Panoramic Sea View (psv) = hide rows with class name panoramic_sea_view. Click Guardian = hide rows with class name Guardian. Problem, when you click  Guardian, do you see the additional row that appears, the JS is toggling the psv row back in instead of keeping it hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to keep a list of selected buttons so that on each click of any button show all the tr first and hide those which are selected.

Check the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sqmcLgz7/7/)

```
jQuery('.features_toggle span.button').on('click', function() {

  jQuery(this).toggleClass('buttonSelected');

  var allFeature = [];
  // Get a list of button ids which are selected.
  jQuery(".features_toggle span.button.buttonSelected").each(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    // make a selector friendly string
    allFeature.push(".elegant_list_properties tr." + this.id);
  });


  jQuery('.elegant_list_properties tr').show();
  jQuery(allFeature.join(", ")).hide(); // join will make comma separated selector

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I dodgy mouse click on copy and paste.
Either way, your solution doesnt show the rows when I click the button again. Keeps them hidden.

Comment: What do you expect if I click Panoramic Sea View then Guarding and then Panoramic Sea View?

Comment: Basically, any button with a red background, hides the corresponding row with the same class. So if PSV and G are both in red, no rows with either class will show. If I click PSV, then G, then PSV = all rows with PSV to show unless they also contain G class. Make sense?

Comment: Updated the fiddle.

Comment: checked your fiddle. If I click PSV it does hide, but then if I click again it does not show. This is why I tried it using toggle.

Comment: @AlexKnopp check the updated fiddle. It should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks you @void. You are the Gary McKinnon of my day right now.